# Is it appropriate to say "Kindly send it through email address at"

Tags: word-choice

Is *Kindly send it through email address at...* an appropriate sentence?

Comment: Please send me the information via email.  My email address is ...  ("Kindly" is a bit stilted, at least in the US.)

Comment: Or, perhaps the simplest of them all, "Please email it to [address here]"

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you would write something like "Kindly send it to the e-mail address yourID@yahoo.com."

In the context of e-mail addresses, "at" refers to "@." People often use the phrasing "Kindly send it to yourID at yahoo.com" on public online forums to avoid automatic copying of the addresses by computer programs used by people who collect addresses to distribute spam.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to say. If you want to mention that email is the medium, you could say

*kindly send it by email to the address...*

If you just want to ask for the email being sent to a particular address then choose

*kindly sent it to the email address...*